# Org mode exporting with customized fonts in different (human) languages

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, odt

I am writing Myanmar (Burmese) and English in org mode and want to export the buffer to LaTeX (PDF), HTML and ODT formats. Since Myanmar is not supported in Babel or Polyglossia packages, I am using Fontspec package with main font set to Padauk. Sample buffer snippet as below.

```
** ဥပမာ
    ဓာတုဗေဒသည် အက်တမ် /သို့မဟုတ်/ ၎င်းတွင်ရှိ ပရိုတွန်၊ _အီလက်ထရွန်နှင့်_ နျူထရွန် တို့ပါဝင်သည့် ရုပ်ဝတ္ထုများ၏ အပြန်အလှန် သက်ရောက်သော အကြောင်းအရာကို သိပ္ပံနည်းကျကျ လေ့လာခြင်းဖြစ်သည်။ ဓာတုဗေဒကို တစ်ခါတစ်ရံ သိပ္ပံ၏ဗဟိုချက်ဘာသာရပ် အဖြစ် မြင်ကြသည်။ အဘယ်ကြောင့်ဆိုသော် ၎င်းသည် များမြှောင်လှစွာသော ဘာသာရပ်များဖြစ်သည့် နက္ခတ္တဗေဒ၊ ရူပဗေဒ၊ material science၊ ဇီဝဗေဒ နှင့် ဘူမိဗေဒ တို့ကို +အချက်ကျကျ+ ဆက်သွယ်နေ၍ဖြစ်သည်။ Some more example of English text here.
```

Paduak has very nice Myanmar fonts but English fonts are not that great. Therefore, when it gets exported to PDF with Xelatex, I am satisfied with Myanmar fonts but want to change the English fonts to something like TeX Gyre Termes fonts. Sample Padauk output as below.
[image: Sample output 1]

If I put LaTeX code in to change the font like `\fontfamily{qtm}\selectfont Some more example of English text here.`, I am able to get the desired font rendered as below.
[image: Sample output 2]

However, this solution is not preferred as the codes are noisy to the eyes and it also messes up with HTML and ODT export.

Is there any way to set Myanmar language to Padauk and English language to the font of my choosing automatically? Probably something like emphasis built-in function in org mode, for e.g. `~some code~`, which gets exported to monospace font. Please note however that I would like to retain built-in emphasis function for both Myanmar and English language.

The ideal solution would be that I need not put in any marker during writing and that when the buffer gets exported, fonts for different languages are assigned different fonts of my choosing automatically.

Answer (score 1):

What you need can be easily met with the ***enhanced** ODT backend*.

**The *enhanced* ODT backend is not available with standard Emacs or Org mode, and you need to install it separately.  See [Installing enhanced ODT Exporter](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt#installation) for detailed instructions.**

To get this

[image: Mixed Burmese + English Text (LibreOffice)]

do this

[image: Mixed Burmese + English Text (Emacs Org mode)]

```
#+ATTR_ODT: :target "extra_styles"
#+begin_src nxml
<style:style style:name="Standard"
             style:family="paragraph"
             style:class="text">
  <style:text-properties style:font-name-complex="Noto Sans Myanmar"
                         style:country-complex="MM"
                         style:font-family-complex="'Noto Sans Myanmar'"
                         style:font-family-generic-complex="swiss"
                         style:font-pitch-complex="variable"
                         style:font-style-name-complex="Regular"
                         style:language-complex="my" />
</style:style>
#+end_src

** ဥပမာ
ဓာတုဗေဒသည် အက်တမ် /သို့မဟုတ်/ ၎င်းတွင်ရှိ ပရိုတွန်၊ _အီလက်ထရွန်နှင့်_ နျူထရွန် တို့ပါဝင်သည့် ရုပ်ဝတ္ထုများ၏
အပြန်အလှန် သက်ရောက်သော အကြောင်းအရာကို သိပ္ပံနည်းကျကျ လေ့လာခြင်းဖြစ်သည်။ ဓာတုဗေဒကို
တစ်ခါတစ်ရံ သိပ္ပံ၏ဗဟိုချက်ဘာသာရပ် အဖြစ် မြင်ကြသည်။ အဘယ်ကြောင့်ဆိုသော် ၎င်းသည်
များမြှောင်လှစွာသော ဘာသာရပ်များဖြစ်သည့် နက္ခတ္တဗေဒ၊ ရူပဗေဒ၊ material science၊
ဇီဝဗေဒ နှင့် ဘူမိဗေဒ တို့ကို +အချက်ကျကျ+ ဆက်သွယ်နေ၍ဖြစ်သည်။ Some more example of
English text here.
```